# Google Play Game Services iOS crash on sign in

Tags: ios, google-play-services

This is my first foray into the world of xcode and objective-c so please bear with me. I've been following the steps listed on the google developer site for implementing google play games services on ios:
https://developers.google.com/games/services/ios/quickstart

Steps 1-7 work fine and I'm able to sign in to Google+ using the GPSignIn object:

> Finished with auth. 2013-05-28 02:37:19.718 MyApp[2012:907] Success
>   signing in to Google! Auth object is GTMOAuth2Authentication
>   0x1d56ab40:
>   {accessToken="ya29.AHES6ZQa59aGdKmrWhKSN0ie_S_CqgLfBqKzlmHXU0Cpnxs",
>   refreshToken="1/A8dCPhVKRRgbsM4Gcp4qlkhNJc9SyyTUEVssN3A-Iro",
>   expirationDate="2013-05-28 10:37:19 +0000"}

Once I implement step 8 though there seems to be a crash in the GPGManager signIn function which I have implemented like so:

```
-(void)startGoogleGamesSignIn
    {
      // The GPPSignIn object has an auth token now. Pass it to the GPGManager.
      [[GPGManager sharedInstance] signIn:[GPPSignIn sharedInstance]
           reauthorizeHandler:^(BOOL requiresKeychainWipe, NSError *error) {
             // If you hit this, auth has failed and you need to authenticate.
             // Most likely you can refresh behind the scenes
             if (requiresKeychainWipe) {
               [[GPPSignIn sharedInstance] signOut];
             }
             [[GPPSignIn sharedInstance] authenticate];
           }];
    }
```

Debug log:

> 013-05-28 02:16:04.742 MyApp[1970:907] Printing the gppsignin instance
>   =  2013-05-28 02:16:04.781 MyApp[1970:907] Printing the gpgmanager instance =  2013-05-28
>   02:16:04.785 MyApp[1970:907] *** Terminating app due to uncaught
>   exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '***
>   -[__NSPlaceholderArray initWithObjects:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[0]'
>   *** First throw call stack: (0x3375d2a3 0x3b3db97f 0x336a734d 0x336a7a79 0x57089 0x56bf5 0x57f2d 0x37bd1 0x36331 0xb27f 0xb10b
>   0x2edcd 0x108d7 0x340986fd 0x33fd81f9 0x33fd8115 0x3343a45f 0x33439b43
>   0x33461fcb 0x336a374d 0x3346242b 0x333c603d 0x33732683 0x33731ee9
>   0x33730cb7 0x336a3ebd 0x336a3d49 0x372562eb 0x355b9301 0xab3d
>   0x3b812b20) libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
>   (lldb)

As far as I can tell I'm not using any NSArrays in my code and I can't get a proper callstack. Is anyone else playing around with this getting similar issues?

Comment: Hello! Any updates on this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Its because you forgot to add PlayGameServices.bundle in your xcode project as in Getting Started Guide on https://developers.google.com/games/services/ios/quickstart

Source: i had same issue.

Answer (score 1):

The official documentation doesn't make this distinction clear enough: unlike the `PlayGameServices.framework` which has to be added to the `Link Binary With Libraries` build phase the `PlayGameServices.bundle` has to be added to the `Copy Bundle Resources` build phase.

PS: Thanks to farroid for pointing out the cause of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Add an all exceptions breakpoint and then when the breakpoint is hit you can use `image lookup --address` at the console, with the addresses from the trace text, to find out where the problem is. Most likely something you think exists is nil when you give it to the GPP classes.