# Google Play Game in ios using Unity3d

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, google-play-services

I am testing out Google Play Game Plugin for Unity3d. I use the code from `Minimal` and when I hit the `authenticate` button I get this error:

```
2014-06-18 09:16:05.610 minimal[20466:60b] GPGSAuthenticateWithCallback.
2014-06-18 09:16:05.612 minimal[20466:60b] GPGSManager initializing and authenticating.
2014-06-18 09:16:05.623 minimal[20466:60b] GPPSignIn initialized.
2014-06-18 09:16:05.623 minimal[20466:60b] GPPSignIn attempting sign in now.
2014-06-18 09:16:05.673 minimal[20466:60b] -[__NSDictionaryM gtm_httpArgumentsString]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1a852890
2014-06-18 09:16:05.674 minimal[20466:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSDictionaryM gtm_httpArgumentsString]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1a852890'
```

1. How can I resolve this issue?
2. I test `minimal` from within Unity3d too get the message authentication fail. Is it possible for me to test in from within Unity3d?

Answer (score 0):

I found out the issue. As I check https://developers.google.com/games/services/ios/quickstart, I solved my issue by going through **Option 2: Manual installation -> Step 6:**

> Add the ObjC linker flag to the app target's build settings. In your
>   target settings, select Build Settings > Linking > Other Linker Flags,
>   then add -ObjC as a flag.

```
Other Linker Flags: -ObjC
```

I found some other people with the similar error but different solution:

[Google Play Game Services iOS crash on sign in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16802039/google-play-game-services-ios-crash-on-sign-in?rq=1)